# .text() on change jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<td><span id="v">77483.2231</span></td>
```

When the #v value changes I want to get an pop-up alert

```
$('#v').change(function() {
    alert("ok");
});
```

That's my code, its not working though, what could be wrong?

Thanks

Jean

Comment: you cannot attach an onChange event to a span. But how does it get edited? YOu've got to hook in there somehow.

Comment: How does the value of the span change?

Comment: why don't you tell us what you're trying to do from a very high level?

Comment: @joni @vincent the change is auto change from the db.

Comment: @Jean auto change from the db? You mean, the page gets reloaded and the server just puts different content into that div? In this case, you'd be definitively wrong with a javascript onChange event..

Comment: @joni, no the value of the span gets refreshed, no page load, its ajaxed

Comment: @ Jean ah ok :D then just apply a callback to your ajax request that does your desired action?

Comment: @joni I have different values else where, so I want to write a .change when the value change.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, .change() only works with form elements

> This event is limited to 
>   elements,  boxes and
>    elements.

From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Either do your code where you change the span text elsewhere in the script or set up some kind of listener to watch and see if it changes?

Further explanation of what you're trying to do (and why) would help.

Comment: That all depends on what it is you're trying to do and what you already have. - To start with why does the text change and who makes the change?

Comment: The text is a change from the db, so when the change is made an alert pops.

Comment: Sorry I missed the last comments on the original post but why can't you run a function on the ajax request callback?

Comment: I still don't think you understand. The answer to your first question is you can't use .change() on a span. Do you call $.ajax to load the content? if so you can add a function in the callback that will notify your set of elements that they've been changed. If magic fairies add content to your site without you knowing you probably need to do something like set a data attribute for the initial content ($('#v').data('org_data',$('#v').text())), then check that with the current content every few second/minutes/hours/weeks. (setInterval('checkStuff()',10000))